# multi threaded processes in python using queue to write to file checking if work had been done

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import multiprocessing as mp



def func(a):

    pthData = "C:/temp/temp.txt"
    with open(pthData, 'r') as file:
        done = file.read().splitlines()

    if a in done:
        return 'done'

    q.put(a)
    return a

def listener(q):

    pthData = "C:/temp/temp.txt"
    m = q.get()
    with open(pthData, 'a') as the_file:
        the_file.write( m + '\n')
        #he_file.write(str(m) + '\n')


a =  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b']


# Make the Pool of workers
pool = ThreadPool(4)

#must use Manager queue here, or will not work
manager = mp.Manager()
q = manager.Queue()    

#put listener to work first
watcher = pool.apply_async(listener, (q,))

pool.starmap(func, a, q)
## TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'AutoProxy[Queue]' and 'int'

pool.starmap(func, a)
## Runs but only writes 'a' to temp file

pool.starmap(func, (a, q))
## func() takes 1 positional argument but 6 were given

pool.apply_async(func, (a, q))
## freezes on pool.join

# Close the pool and wait for the work to finish
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Why is the apply_async freezing on the pool.join()? I tried putting it into a if **name** == '**main**' but it had the same result.

How do I properly call `func` passing 1 argument (a) and the queue (q)?

Comment: Why do you need to use starmap?

Comment: I don't . I tried it after `apply_async` didn't work.

Comment: You want to pass single items from the list to func and have func put the item in the queue if it is not in the file? And you want/need the listener to act on queue items - separate from func?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Then from the queue write them to the file.

Comment: Does `temp.txt` exist before you execute?

Comment: yes, it does...

Answer (score 1):

> How do I properly call func passing 1 argument (a) and the queue (q)?

This at-least does not *freeze*:

- Ensure `temp.txt` exists before execution.
- Add a `q` parameter to `func`.

```
      def func(a,q):
          print(f'func({a})')
          ...
```

- Use `apply_async` in a list comprehension.

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':

        # Make the Pool of workers
        with ThreadPool(4) as pool:
            q = queue.Queue()
            #put listener to work first
            watcher = pool.apply_async(listener, (q,))
            results = [pool.apply_async(func, (item, q)) for item in a]
            # just check stuff
            for result in results:
                result.wait()
                print(result, result.successful(),result.get())
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
```

---

- You will need to work out some other problems like `listener` running once then stopping.
- Many other ways to do this, I used `apply_async` because it was one of the options in your question.
- I like using concurrent.futures myself.
- You may benefit from reading through the search results using variations of `python threading producer consumer site:stackoverflow.com`

Comment: Does this write `a, b, c, d` to temp.txt for you? For me it only gets one letter out of 4 in the file

Comment: @R.M. ... `listener` runs once then *quits* - so it only writes the first letter. Somehow you need `listener` to continually check the queue til it doesn't need to anymore.